# Have a function depend on an unspecified class in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

How do I implement the following pseudo-code in Java:

```
  class A extends B{
    int var[];
   void someFn(var, WANT TO INPUT EITHER a C1 or C2 CLASS HERE){
           //initialize var;
           // Call fn(var,C1 or C2)

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
     ///main stuff
    }

   }

  class B{
     void fn(int var[], C1 c1){return foo;}
     void fn(int var[], C2 c2){return other foo;}
    }
  class C1{stuff here}
  class C2{other stuff here}
```

I tried

```
  class A extends B{
    int var[];
     public static <C> void someFn(var, C Cclass){
        //initialize var;
        // Call fn(var, C1 or C2)
```

But that did not work. I am still sorta new to Java.  I would prefer to not overload `someFn`

Comment: Why not just overload `someFn()`?

Comment: That was my initial implementation.  I shoud have mentioned that it would be nice to not to have to overload `someFn` in case I want to change some other  parts of `someFn`.   The only use of C1 or C2 in `someFn` is when calling fn(var, C1 or C2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generic types

### [JLS-8.1.2. Generic Classes and Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)  says (in part)

> A class is generic if it declares one or more type variables ([§4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)).
>
> These type variables are known as the *type parameters* of the class. The type parameter section follows the class name and is delimited by angle brackets.

### An Example

A `void` function can't return a value. But you could do

```
class A<T> extends B<T> {
}

class B<T>{
    void fn(int var[], T c1){
        return;
    }
}
```

## An Interface

### [JLS Chapter 9. Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9) says (in part)

> An interface declaration introduces a new reference type whose members are classes, interfaces, constants, and abstract methods. This type has no implementation, but otherwise unrelated classes can implement it by providing implementations for its abstract methods.

Program to a common `C` interface and you can avoid generic types.

```
interface C {
   void doSomething();
}
```

with `C1` and `C2` like

```
class C1 implements C {
   void doSomething() {
      // do something
   }
}
```

and

```
class C2 implements C {
   void doSomething() {
      // do something else
   }
}
```

Then your `B` might look like

```
class B {
    void fn(int var[], C c1){
        c1.doSomething();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interfaces are nice, realized I further don't even need the `class B` since overloaded instances of `fn` were the only thing in there, and solved my main problem of not wanting to overload `someFn`.

Answer (score 2):

Now this is simply the implementation of your pseudo code

```
package com.so;

public class A extends B{
     int var[];
     void someFn(int[] var, Object object){
         this.var = var;
         if (object instanceof C1){
             fn(var,(C1) object);    
         }
         else if (object instanceof C2){
             fn(var,(C2) object);    
         }


     }

     public static void main(String[] arguments){
         A a = new A();
         int[] i = {1,2};
         C1 c1 = new C1();
         a.someFn(i, c1);
        }

}

class B{
      void fn(int var[], C1 c1){
          System.out.println("C1 func");
          /*Void can not return even foo*/
          }
      void fn(int var[], C2 c2){
          System.out.println("C2 func");
          /*Void can not return even other foo either*/
          }
}

class C1{}
class C2{}
```

---

**Using Generics**

```
public class A<T> extends B<T>{
     int var[];
     void someFn(int[] var, T t){
         this.var = var;
         fn(var,t);


     }

     public static void main(String[] arguments){
         A<C1> a = new A<C1>();
         int[] i = {1,2};
         C1 c1 = new C1();
         a.someFn(i, c1);

         C2 c2 = new C2();
         //a.someFn(i, c2); //This will give you complie time error because of typesafety (good thing)

         A<C2> a2 = new A<C2>();
         a2.someFn(i, c2);
        }

}

class B<T>{
      void fn(int var[], T c){
          System.out.println(c.getClass().getName() +"func");
          /*Void can not return even foo*/
          }

}

class C1{}
class C2{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to overload `someFn` (and assuming you can't make `C1` and `C2` subclasses of the same parent class or implement the same interface, as in Elliott's answer), the only way I can see is something like

```
void someFn(Whatever var, Object c) {
    if (c instanceof C1) {
        b.fn(var, (C1)c);
    } else if (c instanceof C2) {
        b.fn(var, (C2)c);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid object passed to someFn");
    }
}
```

(I'm assuming that since `fn` isn't static in your question, you have to have an object of type `B` to use it on; if my assumption is wrong, modify the code accordingly.)

The thing is, overloads have to be resolved at compile time, not run time.  That is, the program *cannot*, while it's running, look at an object's class and decide which of the two `fn`'s to call.  In order for the compiler to pick the correct one, you have to tell it which class you're expecting the parameter to be.  That's what the cast to `(C1)` or `(C2)` does.